# Error when adding jar dependence in Zeppelin

Tags: apache-zeppelin

Spark works normally in Zeppelin but when I add a jar dependency and run something like:

```
val df = spark.read.json("path/file1")
```

I got the the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Jackson version is too old 2.5.4
```

If I run it a second time I got:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$
```

(Not sure why the error changes for the second run)

If I do not attach the jar the code works normally. Is this connected with conflicts maybe?

Tried to do something like the following in the interpreter option in Spark but still the same error:

```
artifact: path/utils.jar
exclude: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind (Is this the correct way to write how to exclude jackson?)
```

Any insights?